# Create roles with multiple policies in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I have 2 different type of resources and each of them needs own role.
I'm going to use Terraform to create 2 different roles with 3 and 4 different policies attached to them respectively. Could you please advise some best practices for this?

I assume if will create several "aws_iam_policy_document" "data" objects, then I can combine them in 2 different lists and call my create "create_policy" module and with "count" functions to create all policies. Then if I can somehow return in module "module" output list of created policies ARNs, I can create roles and attach to them this policies. I'm stuck there and don't know how to cobine ARNs and return them as a list in output.

Comment: I don't have a 100% clear picture of how you're trying to setup the Terraform configurations, but I can offer you some general advice that might help.  IMO, sometimes modules in Terraform are great, and other times they aren't a good fit and trying to force a configuration to use them just backs you into a corner.

So if you have Terraform configs that define each of the roles, you could just create inline policies based on the iam policy documents (data objects) there.  You get the benefit of shared policy documents, but add them to each role w/o modules.

Comment: Do you have any TF code example to show and whey are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I just added several policies in one "aws_iam_policy_document" "data" object.